# Dropdown menu: Affecting elements based on hover over parent elements HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu. For some reason, the dropdown doesn't appear when hovering over the parent element, and the arrow isn't hidden, and not in the proper spot. I have the below code:

```css
.nav-item-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  float: right;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-wrapper:hover,
.dropdown:hover,
#nav1:hover+#dropdown1,
#nav2:hover+#dropdown2 {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown-arrow-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 12.5px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px lightgrey;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-item-wrapper">
  <a href="" class="nav-item" id="nav1">Title</a>
  <div class="dropdown-wrapper" id="dropdown-wrapper-1">
    <div class="dropdown-arrow-wrapper">
      <div class="dropdown-arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown col" id="dropdown1">
      <a href="" class="nav-item">Element</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-item">Element</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-item">Element</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-item">Element</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-item">Element</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would need the HTML components to remain the same as I need to fit this dropdown element into a navigation header. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What arrow do you mean? In the snippet. 

Comment: @deEr I implemented `dropdown-arrow-wrapper` and `dropdown-arrow` above `dropdown col`. It's not shown in the snippet for some reason. Ideally, the arrow looks attached to the top of the dropdown col and only appears when the dropdown does.

Comment: Oh, I had a wrong angle at my laptop.  I can see the arrow now. [This is how far I got.](https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/dzhqkneg/26/)

Comment: @deEr. Thanks for your help. I actually have two dropdown menus next to each other. When implementing your above code, hovering anywhere in the header sets the display for both dropdown menus to flex. How can you implement two seperate dropdown menus side by side?

Comment: The `+` in CSS is only for elements, that are **immediately** adjacent. https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048t#toc-qa4w-x-y While the idea was good, there is no better way as at the JSFiddle. Can you structure your dropdowns under a different `parent`? And can you please give the code of the second dropdown?

Comment: To show you what `+` means: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/dzhqkneg/34/ .

Comment: @deEr. Thank you for your help. Linked is a least most of the code I have (I was unable to replicate the exact code for some reason). For some reason, the entire row shifts to the right upon hovering. Here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/e1ua0prj/11/

Comment: That is large. Do you have an image or mockup, of how you imagine it to be? 